# How to fade out error prompts with Validation Engine Plug in for jQuery?

Tags: jquery, validation, prompt

I'm using from it https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine

I wonder how to make the prompts should to close themselves by 4 seconds without clicking the prompts to closethe code line is 26 from jquery.validationEngine.js, it looks like:

```
$(".formError").live("click", function() {
    $(this).fadeOut(150, function() {
        // remove prompt once invisible
       $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

I tried to remove "click" inside of live, but it didn't work because the validations don't appear, anyone can help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check edited answer... may help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the autohide option.
Check the documentation of validationEngine or the validationEngine.js - at the bottom of the .js file you'll see:

```
    // Auto-hide prompt
    autoHidePrompt: true,
    // Delay before auto-hide
    autoHideDelay: 3000,
    // Fade out duration while hiding the validations
    fadeDuration: 0.3
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're trying to make sure the "click" event only happens once?  If so, use `unbind()` to undo all event listeners.  If you want to be specific about which event listener, use a parameter: `unbind("click")` like this:

```
$(".formError").live("click", function() {
$(this).unbind("click");
$(this).fadeOut(150, function() {
    // remove prompt once invisible
   $(this).remove();
});
```

});

When the `unbind("click")` is called, that particular `.formError` element will no longer have the click event listener, but all the others still will.

EDIT:
When unbinding all events tied to event listeners initialized with `live()`, you must use `die()`.  Sorry, I hadn't `live()`'d in a while, so I forgot you had to `die()`.

Comment: Thanks for answer but the results are same